# Words are being cut-off in html mail

Tags: html, css, email

I've created a couple of html email. They are being send through our Laravel application. But our customer reported that words are being cut weirdly.

[image]

I haven't used the word-break property at all. So I don't know where this issue is coming from.
The customer is using Internet Explorer 11 and Lotus Notes (never heard of that).

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Baloise</title>
            
        <style>
            /* ------------------------------------- 
                GLOBAL 
        ------------------------------------- */
        * { 
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        * { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

        img { 
            max-width: 100%; 
        }
        .collapse {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        body {
            -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; 
            -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; 
            width: 100%!important; 
            height: 100%;
        }

        table {
            border-spacing: 0px !important;
        }


        /* ------------------------------------- 
                ELEMENTS 
        ------------------------------------- */
        a { color: #2BA6CB;}

        .btn {
            text-decoration:none;
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #666;
            padding:10px 16px;
            font-weight:bold;
            margin-right:10px;
            text-align:center;
            cursor:pointer;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        p.callout {
            padding:15px;
            background-color:#ECF8FF;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        p {
            color: #707272;
        }

        .callout a {
            font-weight:bold;
            color: #2BA6CB;
        }

        table.social {
        /*  padding:15px; */
            background-color: #ebebeb;
            
        }
        .social .soc-btn {
            padding: 3px 7px;
            font-size:12px;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            text-decoration:none;
            color: #FFF;font-weight:bold;
            display:block;
            text-align:center;
        }
        a.fb { background-color: #3B5998!important; }
        a.tw { background-color: #1daced!important; }
        a.gp { background-color: #DB4A39!important; }
        a.ms { background-color: #000!important; }

        .sidebar .soc-btn { 
            display:block;
            width:100%;
        }

        /* ------------------------------------- 
                HEADER 
        ------------------------------------- */
        table.head-wrap { width: 100%;}

        .header.container table td.logo { padding: 15px; }
        .header.container table td.label { padding: 15px; padding-left:0px;}


        /* ------------------------------------- 
                BODY 
        ------------------------------------- */
        table.body-wrap { width: 100%;}


        /* ------------------------------------- 
                FOOTER 
        ------------------------------------- */
        table.footer-wrap { width: 100%; clear:both!important;
        }
        .footer-wrap .container td.content  p { border-top: 1px solid rgb(215,215,215); padding-top:15px;}
        .footer-wrap .container td.content p {
            font-size:10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            
        }


        /* ------------------------------------- 
                TYPOGRAPHY 
        ------------------------------------- */
        h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom:15px; color:#000;
        }
        h1 small, h2 small, h3 small, h4 small, h5 small, h6 small { font-size: 60%; color: #6f6f6f; line-height: 0; text-transform: none; }

        h1 { font-weight:200; font-size: 44px;}
        h2 { font-weight:200; font-size: 37px;}
        h3 { font-weight:500; font-size: 27px;}
        h4 { font-weight:500; font-size: 23px;}
        h5 { font-weight:900; font-size: 17px;}
        h6 { font-weight:900; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; color:#444;}

        .collapse { margin:0!important;}

        p, ul { 
            margin-bottom: 10px; 
            font-weight: normal; 
            font-size:14px; 
            line-height:1.6;
        }
        p.lead { font-size:17px; }
        p.last { margin-bottom:0px;}

        ul li {
            margin-left:5px;
            list-style-position: inside;
        }

        /* ------------------------------------- 
                SIDEBAR 
        ------------------------------------- */
        ul.sidebar {
            background:#ebebeb;
            display:block;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        ul.sidebar li { display: block; margin:0;}
        ul.sidebar li a {
            text-decoration:none;
            color: #666;
            padding:10px 16px;
        /*  font-weight:bold; */
            margin-right:10px;
        /*  text-align:center; */
            cursor:pointer;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
            border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
            display:block;
            margin:0;
        }
        ul.sidebar li a.last { border-bottom-width:0px;}
        ul.sidebar li a h1,ul.sidebar li a h2,ul.sidebar li a h3,ul.sidebar li a h4,ul.sidebar li a h5,ul.sidebar li a h6,ul.sidebar li a p { margin-bottom:0!important;}



        /* --------------------------------------------------- 
                RESPONSIVENESS
                Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure. 
        ------------------------------------------------------ */

        /* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
        .container {
            display:block!important;
            max-width:600px!important;
            margin:0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */
            clear:both!important;
        }

        .container-body {
            display:block!important;
            max-width:560px!important;
            margin:0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */
            clear:both!important;
        }

        /* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
        .content {
            padding:15px;
            max-width:600px;
            margin:0 auto;
            display:block; 
        }

        /* Let's make sure tables in the content area are 100% wide */
        .content table { width: 100%; }


        /* Odds and ends */
        .column {
            width: 300px;
            float:left;
        }
        .column tr td { padding: 15px; }
        .column-wrap { 
            padding:0!important; 
            margin:0 auto; 
            max-width:600px!important;
        }
        .column table { width:100%;}
        .social .column {
            width: 280px;
            min-width: 279px;
            float:left;
        }

        /* Be sure to place a .clear element after each set of columns, just to be safe */
        .clear { display: block; clear: both; }


        /* ------------------------------------------- 
                PHONE
                For clients that support media queries.
                Nothing fancy. 
        -------------------------------------------- */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            
            a[class="btn"] { display:block!important; margin-bottom:10px!important; background-image:none!important; margin-right:0!important;}

            div[class="column"] { width: auto!important; float:none!important;}
            
            table.social div[class="column"] {
                width:auto!important;
            }

        }
        </style>

        </head>
        
        <body bgcolor="#f7f9fa">

        <!-- HEADER -->
        <table class="head-wrap">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="header container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        
                    <div class="content">
                    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <img style="display: block;" width="150" src="images/logo-baloise.png" alt="Baloise insurance" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="15" style="height: 15px; line-height: 15px;">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #e3f3f9;">

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                        
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table><!-- /HEADER -->


        <!-- BODY -->
        <table class="body-wrap">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

                    <div class="content">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 0 50px 0 50px;">
                                <p style="color: #707272;">  
                                    <font style="color: #003695; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Beste makelaar,<br /></font><br />
                                    De beheerder heeft de offerte  [ABR of BA Tienjargie] voor [klantnaam] met offertenummer [offertenummer] opgesteld.
                                    U kunt die terugvinden op de <a style="color: #003695; text-decoration: underline;" href="https://saferbusiness.be/nl/" target="_blank">Safer Business-website</a> en is ook beschikbaar als pdf in deze e-mail.
                                    <br /><br />
                                    Met vriendelijke groet
                                    <br />
                                    <font style="color:#003695; font-weight: bold;">Baloise Insurance</font>
                                </p> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div><!-- /content -->
                                            
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img style="display: block;" src="images/line.png" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table><!-- /BODY -->

        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <table class="footer-wrap">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="container">
                    
                        <!-- content -->
                        <div class="content">
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                
                                <!-- content here -->

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                        </div><!-- /content -->
                        
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table><!-- /FOOTER -->

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You can check the full code over here: You can check the full code over here: 
https://codepen.io/dennisperremans/pen/OrVqpW

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please edit the question and add the *relevant* parts of the code, possibly in a runnable snippet? Questions are supposed to be self-contained, so they're a useful contribution for whoever has the same problem in the future. (Also, external links tend to eventually disappear.)

Comment: Okay, I've added the code in my question.

Comment: try with `white-space:pre;`